# Escape sed delimiter character when also regex special character

Tags: regex, sed, escaping, delimiter

Say I have want to match the string `foo.`. My regex would be `foo\.`, to escape the special meaning of the `.` character.

Now say that in my sed command, I use the `.` as a delimiter.

For a search like, say, `cat`, this works fine.

```
echo cat | sed 's.cat.dog.g'
```

But when I have a literal `.` in my search string, I run into a problem. I would think, that since the `.` is my delimiter, my regex `foo\.` should become `foo\\\.`. Ideally, the first pass of unescaping would be done by sed to make this into `foo\.`, and then this would get passed along to the regular expression engine.

But instead, it matches `cat\\\.`

```
echo 'cat.' | sed 's.cat\\\..dog.g' # cat.
echo 'cat\.' | sed 's.cat\\\..dog.g' # dog
```

Is there any way to make this work with a literal `.` when `.` is used as a delimiter?

I'm asking this question because I want to be able to have a function

```
function escapeForExtendedSed ($str, $delimiter = "/") { ... }
```

which can escape correctly depending on what the caller is using as a delimiter.

Comment: Your function signature doesn't look like a BASH function.

Comment: Similar to csv files I think you'd need to use quotes or some other secondary quote like delimiter to specify to any parser when you your literal character should not be used as a delimiter. Otherwise that special character is ambiguous.

Comment: @anubhava The function signature is in PHP (I'm doing an `exec` from PHP, for reasons that aren't really relevant to the question).

Comment: Does the `sedstr` function from [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29626460/258523) help here by obviating the need for alternate delimiters?

Comment: @Etan I don't actually need alternative delimiters - I just use an escaping function usually myself (and in PHP, I'd just use strtr or something like that) - but I was just curious if there was any way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me:

```
echo 'cat.' | sed 's.cat[\.].dog.g' # cat.
```

Comment: That's matching `cat` followed by any character, not a period specifically. Try replacing `'cat.'` with `'cat@'` in the above to see what I mean.

Comment: Brilliant thinking. And I came up with one that works for left bracket as delimiter based off of your answer, but you need the `-E` flag to make it work: `echo 'cat[' | sed -E 's[cat(\[)[dog[g'`. EDIT: Or you can use `\(` and `\)` without the E flag, I forgot.